# SQL Case Sensitive String Compare

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you compare strings so that the comparison is true only if the cases of each of the strings are equal as well.  For example:

```
Select * from a_table where attribute = 'k'
```

...will return a row with an attribute of 'K'. I do not want this behaviour.

Comment: It might not be what you need but you can change the Collation or use a specific Collation in your query.

Comment: Which SQL product?

Answer (score 517, accepted):

```
Select * from a_table where attribute = 'k' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Did the trick.

Comment: I'd normally use Latin1_General_Bin

Comment: Yes, the Standard approach is to use a case-insensitive collation, though the collations themselves are vendor-specific. Is yours SQL Server syntax?

Comment: In my case, I have 1 column in my db that is case-sensitive. I needed to compare it to a standard (CI) column. I used a variation of this

WHERE Foo.Bar = (Baz.Bar COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)

Comment: Thanks but what is Latin1_General_CS_AS  ?? Is it special keyword?

Comment: @VijaySinghRana `Latin1_General_CS_AS` is a specification of the collation. Collation refers to a set of rules that determine how data is sorted and compared. See [this page](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3302341/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm) for more information.

Comment: @amccormack Is this work all types of DB? How about Netezza

Comment: In SQL Server, I would recommend checking the current collation of the table first. For example, if the collation is `Traditional_Spanish_CI_AS`, use `Traditional_Spanish_CS_AS` in your query

Comment: will there be performance issues when it comes queried by thousands of users (for example login)?

Comment: This also works well inline for JSON columns like this: 
json_value(
    tableName.jsonColumnName 
 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS --For Case-sensitive matching of extracted values.
 , '$.sectionName.attributeName'
  ) = 'MYUPPERVALUE'

Answer (score 62):

You can also convert that attribute as **case sensitive** using this syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN Column1 VARCHAR(200)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Now your search will be **case sensitive**.

If you want to make that column **case insensitive** again, then use

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN Column1 VARCHAR(200)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: I have nvarchar type column. Above query didn't work for me. Any reason?

Answer (score 32):

You Can easily Convert columns to VARBINARY(Max Length), The length must be the maximum you expect to avoid defective comparison, It's enough to set length as the column length. Trim column help you to compare the real value except space has a meaning and valued in your table columns, This is a simple sample and as you can see I Trim the columns value and then convert and compare.:

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(250),LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1))) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(250),LTRIM(RTRIM(Column2)))
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 23):

Just as another alternative you could use HASHBYTES, something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a_table 
WHERE HASHBYTES('sha1', attribute) = HASHBYTES('sha1', 'k')
```

Comment: What about collisions? It'd be rare but I assume there would be multiple strings that hash to the same value.

Comment: Yes possible, but extremely rare on such a simple string example I would have thought.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner why not first do the compare and if they match then also check for hashbytes? We could make this a function and invoke it like StringsAreCaseSensitiveEqual(a, b) => a = b AND HASHBYTES('sha1', a) = HASHBYTES('sha1', b)

Answer (score 14):

simplifying the general answer

> SQL Case Sensitive String Compare

These examples may be helpful:

```
Declare @S1 varchar(20) = 'SQL'
Declare @S2 varchar(20) = 'sql'

  
if @S1 = @S2 print 'equal!' else print 'NOT equal!' -- equal (default non-case sensitivity for SQL

if cast(@S1 as binary) = cast(Upper(@S2) as binary) print 'equal!' else print 'NOT equal!' -- equal

if cast(@S1 as binary) = cast(@S2 as binary) print 'equal!' else print 'NOT equal!' -- not equal

if  @S1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  = Upper(@S2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  print 'equal!' else print 'NOT equal!' -- equal

if  @S1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  = @S2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  print 'equal!' else print 'NOT equal!' -- not equal
```

The convert is probably more efficient than something like runtime calculation of hashbytes, and I'd expect the collate may be even faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `attribute` as `BINARY` or use `INSTR` or `STRCMP` to perform your search.

Comment: This reply doesn't seem to be about SQL Server per the question tag. That DBMS lacks these `INSTR` and `STRCMP` functions.