# Symfony2 user authentication against database with bcrypt returns 'bad credentials'

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am trying to authenticate user against database. It works well for plaintext as password encoding. But when I am using bccrypt to encrypt password it gives 'bad credentials'.

Here is my security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    foo: { password: test , roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: versionR\userBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

    encoders:
        versionR\userBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 5
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Entity class

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace versionR\userBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string")
     */
    private $address;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and user repository class

```
<?php

namespace versionR\userBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return \versionR\userBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->getEntityName() === $class
        || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }
}
```

I use this command class to create test users

```
<?php

namespace versionR\userBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use versionR\userBundle\Entity\User;

    class userCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
    {
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this
                ->setName('versionR:users')
                ->setDescription('Add Jobeet users')
                ->addArgument('username', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The username')
                ->addArgument('password', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The password')
                ->addArgument('email', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The email')
                ->addArgument('address', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The address')
            ;
        }

        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            $username = $input->getArgument('username');
            $password = $input->getArgument('password');
            $email = $input->getArgument('email');
            $address = $input->getArgument('address');

            $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername($username);
            // encode the password
            $factory = $this->getContainer()->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
            $encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setAddress($address);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $output->writeln(sprintf('Added %s user with password %s', $username, $password));
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working? thanks.

Comment: Are you encoding the password with the same encryption method?

Comment: yes, It is done in side the command class execute method. I have used security encoder there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since code is correct. Problem was in the database, to use bcrypt there should be enough space in the database password field. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d) password field should be either `CHAR(60)` or `BINARY(60)`. If it is less than that half of the encrypted string will be saved and it turns out bad credentials.