# BINARY type MYSQL field with bcrypt

Tags: mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I was taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d) regarding the field length and type to use for bcrypt hashes. Several the answers mention using the `BINARY` MYSQL column type. However, when reading from this column with the mysql node.js module, it reads BINARY columns into a buffer type rather than a string. The bcrypt compare function `bcrypt.compare(password, hash, callback)` does not like the buffer type:

```
Error: data and hash must be strings
    at node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:150:16
```

This leads me to two questions:

First, I assume that what I want to do is `hash_buffer.toString()`, but I notice in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) that there are different character encodings that can be used. I'm not sure what the correct encoding to use is since the data doesn't really represent actual characters. Since I want the binary data to remain unchanged, I would guess ASCII. Can anyone confirm this?

Second, I don't understand why not to use the `CHAR` data type. The hash is specifically made to be a printable string. I understand that the MYSQL comparisons might not be made as expected, but there is no appropriate time to search for or sort by a password hash anyways.

Comment: Considering that a Bcrypt hash is ASCII, you may as well just do `hash_buffer.toString()`.

Comment: Do you mean because the default, utf8, is a superset of ASCII?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it makes sense to use BINARY columns to store bcrypt hashes if MySQL is the one doing the comparison. A binary collation will prevent unwanted comparison results, e.g. `'A'` being equal to `'a'`; this makes a big difference in Base64 encoding.

However, if the comparison is exclusively performed in the application, you can save yourself the trouble and use a regular CHAR column for storing the hash.

Comment: How could MYSQL possibly be doing the comparison? You have to read the hash to get the salt and cost values before hashing the candidate password.

Comment: @bytesized Bcrypt can also use md5 to generate a hash; it's a generic algorithm, so it's entirely possible that hashes could be looked up with a simple query; of course, i don't suggest you should do this.