# Storing and validating encrypted password for login in Pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, password-encryption

I am trying to validate an encrypted password for `login` purposes in Pyramid. So that if the user and password match then the system will authorize the user. At the moment I am finding it difficult to write a function to compare passwords when one is encrypted in the database and the the password being entered into Pyramid's `login` form is unencrypted. Right now, I have no verification occurring in the login view.

I am new to this entire process of working with security measures/code and want to do this right. I was looking at this [Auth tutorial](http://pyramid.chromaticleaves.com/simpleauth/), however the encryption in the `User` class is slightly different and I am using Pyramid's Auth kit. Any guidance on how to do this successfully and smartly would be highly appreciated.

*Software: Python 2.7.9, Pyramid 1.5.7, SQLAlchemy 1.0.9*

---

database class:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(300))
    password = Column(String(300), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = hashlib.sha224(password).hexdigest()
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(username ='%s', password='%s', email='%s')>" % (self.username, self.password, self.email)
```

views

```
@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='templates/login.jinja2')
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='templates/login.jinja2')
def login(request):
    login_url = request.route_url('login')
    referrer = request.url
    if referrer == login_url:
        referrer = '/' # never use the login form itself as came_from
    came_from = request.params.get('came_from', referrer)
    message = ''
    login = ''
    password = ''
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        login = request.params['login']
        password = request.params['password']

        user = api.retrieve_user(login) # need some way to validate password
        if user is not None: # need to check user/password here, redirect if wrong
            headers = remember(request, login)
            return HTTPFound(location = came_from,
                             headers = headers)
            message = 'Failed login'

    return dict(
        message = message,
        url = request.application_url + '/login',
        came_from = came_from,
        login = login,
        password = password,
        )
```

Comment: Please do not store user passwords using sha224, use a proper library that allows you to store passwords securely (such as [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please modify your code, add the excellent passlib library, and use secure password storage using bcrypt as the hashing algorithm.

In your projects setup.py add the following as requirements:

- bcrypt
- passlib

And then use the following code snippet for your model:

```
from passlib.hash import bcrypt

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(300))
    password = Column(String(300), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = bcrypt.encrypt(password)
        self.email = email

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.verify(password, self.password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(username ='%s', password='%s', email='%s')>" % (self.username, self.password, self.email)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I had no idea. I updated my code to reflect this stronger system. Cheers!

Comment: It was recently brought to my attention that using a context manager may help, since it allows you to easily switch to a new algorithm when the time comes: https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.context-tutorial.html#module-passlib.context

Comment: The code here is now starting throw some issues: `passlib.registry: DEBUG: registered 'bcrypt' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.bcrypt.bcrypt'>
passlib.handlers.bcrypt: DEBUG: 'bcrypt' backend lacks '$2$' support`

Comment: Looks like the bcrypt library I recommended doesn't support the salt mechanism used by pass lib. Take a look at these backends supported here and verify if it works with pass lib for that hashing algorithm, or change the salt algorithm: https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html#index-0

Comment: These days, passlib emits a deprecation warning when using `bcrypt.encrypt()`. We should use `bcrypt.hash()` instead.

Comment: Are you sure about the `String(300)` for the `password` column type? From [what I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882472/1720199) and also what I can observe `len(bcrypt.hash("test"))` this could very well be `String(60)`.

Comment: @cglacet: I used the code the original poster had. You'd probably want to use something that is longer than what just `bcrypt` requires so that you can switch algorithms later. Passlib has a lot of functionality around that which will allow you to easily upgrade users to a new hashing scheme in the future.

Answer (score 3):

## WARNING INSECURE CODE FOLLOWS

**The code below is NOT a SECURE and SAFE way to store/verify user passwords. Please use a library that provides secure password storage, such as [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/) which is specifically designed to securely store passwords.**

---

You hash the user's password in your `User.__init__` using `self.password = hashlib.sha224(password).hexdigest()`. Just use a similar method to validate it:

```
class User(Base):
    # Your existing code unchanged

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return self.password == hashlib.sha224(password).hexdigest()
```

And use it in your view:

```
user = api.retrieve_user(login)
if user is not None and user.validate_password(password):
    # You logic on success
```

Comment: I was trying to validate without the addition of the ` hash...` code. This was so simple !!! Thank you so much for clarifying. I was going crazy over this. One more question. I notice if the user login is wrong it doesn't show the failed login message. Is that due to the placement of message after the return? Should I move it up? So I can redirect to create an account?

Comment: @thesayhey Yes, your `message = 'Failed login'` seems to be indented too much. Remove 4 spaces and you should be good.

Comment: Please do not use sha224 directly for the password. Use a proper library such as passlib!