# Invalid username or password at login() using BlowfishPasswordHasher in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: authentication, cakephp, blowfish, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

I'm using **CakePHP 2.7.8** to build an admin panel. My project contains multiple admins instead of users. That's why I have an `admins` table in the database and not an `users` table.

I'm using `BlowfishHasher` for hashing passwords, and it's working fine. Passwords are hashed before saving to database.

But `login()` returns:

```
Invalid username or password, try again
```

**Table admins:**

```
CREATE TABLE `admins` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

**Admins model : Admin.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher','Controller/Component/Auth');
/**
 * Admin Model
 *
 */
class Admin extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */

    public $displayField = 'first_name';


        public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
            if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])){
                $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
                        );
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

**Admins Controller : AdminsController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Admins Controller
 *
 * @property Admin $Admin
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 * @property FlashComponent $Flash
 * @property SessionComponent $Session
 */
class AdminsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Flash', 'Session');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Admin->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('admins', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
/**
 * login function
 */
        public function login(){
            if($this->request->is('post')) {
                if($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }

/**
 * logout function
 */
        public function logout(){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
}
```

**App Controller : AppController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Flash',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect'=>array(
                'controller'=>'admins',
                'action'=>'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array(
                'controller'=>'admins',
                'action'=>'login'
            ),
            'authenticate'=>array(
                'Form'=>array(
                    'passwordHasher'=>'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array(
                'userModel' => 'Admin'
            )
        );
        $this->Auth->allow('login','add','index');
    }
}
```

**Login view : login.ctp**

```
<div class="users form">
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('admin'); ?>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('username'); 
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing your `password` field from `VARCHAR(255)` to `BINARY(60)`.

Remember to clear your models cache after doing so.

See the following question for further details:

- [What column type/length should I use for storing a Bcrypt hashed password in a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5881169/3144159)

---

**Edit**

Also the `AuthComponent` configuration defined in the `$components` array is being overwritten in `beforeFilter()`.

Try replacing the following code:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array(
        'userModel' => 'Admin'
    )
);
```

with:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate[AuthComponent::ALL] = array(
    'userModel' => 'Admin'
);
```

---

**Edit 2**

In your view, you have to replace

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('admin'); ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Admin'); ?>
```

Case is important.

Comment: no effect again. On debug using code by @object-manipulator , Password is hashing differently each time login is called with same username password.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Blowfish uses a  random salt every time. Have you implemented both the above modifications? Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: I do have implemented both modifications but still there is no effect.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your login form. Please post the `login.ctp` view.

Comment: See my last edit. Please note that it's not one solution or the other. Everything mentioned in my answer must be taken care of.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally it worked. Your 'Edit 1' and 'Edit 2' both worked and finally its working.

Comment: sorry for the downvote you have received by someone. I have upvoted your answer but since I'm new here and my reputation is under 15, it will be automatically upvoted from my side once I achieve 15 reputation.

Comment: hey! although login is working by visiting `/admins/login` manually but on accessing unauthorized module before login is now redirecting to `/users/login` which does not exist instead of redirecting to `/admins/login` also after login `loginRedirect` is not working and it redirects to last page requested before login()

Comment: You need to add option `'loginAction'` to the `$components['Auth']` array. See [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers). Regarding `'loginRedirect'`, it's a feature. See [Identifying users and logging them in](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the problem you've posted, I think there's a chance that your password isn't hashing properly when you're logging in.

Try a bit of debugging in your login action:

```
    public function login(){

        if($this->request->is('post')) {

            App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher','Controller/Component/Auth');

            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();

            $this->request->data['Admin']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                   $this->request->data['Admin']['password']
            );

            pr($this->request->data);

            exit;

            // Take a look at this $this->request->data["Admin"]["password"] field and compare it with the password you have in the database. Do they match?

            if($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

Peace! xD

Comment: Debugging gives different hash every time login is requested with same username and password. This is what I get on debug `Notice (8): Undefined index: Admin [APP/Controller/AdminsController.php, line 135]
Array
(
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [username] => qwerty
            [password] => qwerty
        )

    [Admin] => Array
        (
            [password] => $2a$10$Xx9VTgAhUnYApkLNXeQ2sOEJDuvGqYB4ZWz9MfD6p9w3YxGKaIFdC
        )

)` and the password in the database is `$2a$10$x4S46.KX9Okq7Kzedf0J3e3xuX41UTkRMzr7qhhSGR/kDdKOzC.Zi`