# Why should a bcrypt() hash be stored in (var)binary?

Tags: php, mysql, bcrypt

In our php application, we generate password hashes with `password_hash()` (using bcrypt).

bcrypt hashes [should be stored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882472/125075) in `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` (MySQL).

I totally understand this requirement if the comparison and/or search is done inside the database. (collation, case sensitive vs case insensitive).

If the database is only used as storage, and the comparision is done on the php application with `password_verify()`, can we stay with `CHAR`or `VARCHAR`?

IF not, why?

Comment: Do you have to keep it in binary. I think it should be whatever's convenient. You can probably store space with binary but it's probably not going to be a massive gain

Comment: We use varchar for our password_hash() storage

Comment: Actually we would prefere (var)char. But I read this and could not find use cases with mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5882472/125075

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the result of [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is something you can save in a normal `VARCHAR(255)` column, it's not binary data, just a string that looks like:

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

These are, of course, case sensitive but they'll never use anything but regular letters, numbers, and a select few bits of syntax.

This column does not need to be indexed, in fact that would make almost no sense. The `password_verify()` function works against a specific password and is deliberately slow, testing versus every user in the system would take a long time. This is to make it harder for people to brute-force guess passwords.