# password encryption in parse

Tags: php, bcrypt

As parse.com is shutting down its services, I have to migrate to mysql as of now. But I can't seem to get its password generation method.

Sample password is:

"$2a$10$oNQjqXhZjWHVb.ock1Lfs.D4yeHhtaEFdiuHNIkSsambfsSCix/96"

I read few sources and got that it uses bcrypt for password generation with cost as 10.
Still I am not able to get the concept and implement the same in PHP(in which I am building my APIs for my app).

Below is the link for the same, which I came across:

[What column type/length should I use for storing a Bcrypt hashed password in a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d/5882472#5882472)

Can anyone please help me build the same password generation method in php so that I don't loose out on my existing app users (I need to verify password for login and as well as generate one upon registration).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `password_verify()`:

```
$hash = '$2a$10$oNQjqXhZjWHVb.ock1Lfs.D4yeHhtaEFdiuHNIkSsambfsSCix/96'; // e.g. coming from database
$userInput = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null; // coming from user input form

if (password_verify($userInput, $hash)) {
    // user password valid
}
else {
    // user password invalid
}
```

Comment: Use `password_hash()` for registration: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: that doesn't produce the same result as I have mentioned..thats why asked this question. Password hash produce result in different format.

Comment: I guess you don't understand at all how `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` work. Read the documentation first, then just try it. It will work.