# Proper way to store BCrypt Hashes on MySQL

Tags: mysql, hash, bcrypt

Searching for the proper way to store BCrypt hashes in MySQL I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d) and it only made me more confuse.

The accepted answer point out that we should use:

`CHAR(60) BINARY or BINARY(60)`

But other people on the comments argue that instead we should use:

`CHAR(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin`

or even:

`COLLATE latin1_general_cs`

I am not a specialist on databases so **could anyone explain me the difference between all these options and which one is truly better for storing BCrypt hashes?**

Comment: As far as I know, a cryptographic hash is a stream of bits (i.e. binary) but is often represented as plain text. What format do you need to store?

Comment: Your question is dangerously close to *"Could someone please read the documentation on MySQL data types for me and make an executive summary?"*

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, a hash is a stream of bits and yes its encoded as plain text, but all these storage options will lead to different types of behaviors on the database.

Comment: @Tomalak that's really not my intention, I have read the documentation for BINARY and CHAR and the collation differences for _bin types, yet, I can't see the benefits of each other and how they compare, their caveats and surprises along the way, so my intention is actually to ask someone more experienced then I am on how these two options compare.

Comment: @mFeinstein You should offer a  bounty. I think it's an important question

Comment: Yeah, I think I will... But if you want to help, upvoting and favoring the question helps promoting it as well :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is in the line of "what is proper", rather than "what will work".

Do not use `latin1`.  Sure, it might work, but it is ugly to claim that the encrypted string is text when it is not.

Ditto for saying `CHAR...`.

Simply say `BINARY(...)` if fixed length or `VARBINARY(...)` if it can vary in length.

However, there is a gotcha... Whose BCrypt are you using?  Does it return binary data?  Or a hex string?  Or maybe even Base64?

My above answer assumed it returns binary data.

If it returns 60 hex digits, then store `UNHEX(60_hex_digits)` into `BINARY(30)` so that it is packed smaller.

If it is Base64, then `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` would be "proper".  (latin1 with a case-sensitive collation would also work.)

If it is binary, then, again, `BINARY(60)` is the 'proper' way to do it.

The link you provided looks like Base64, but is it?  And is it *up to* 60 characters?  Then I would use

```
VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin
```

And explicitly state the charset/collation for the column, thereby overriding the database and/or table "defaults".

All the Base64 chars (and $) are ascii; no need for a more complex charset.  Collating with a `..._bin` means "compare bytes exactly"; more specifically "don't do case folding".  Since Base64 depends on distinguishing between upper and lower case letters, you don't want case folding.

Comment: I don't think we can consider bcrypt as a pure base64 string, since it will always have it's prefix "$2a$" or "$2b$" or "$2y$", which could vary in any future updates to the protocol, and the cost parameter (something like $10$). Currently, the hashes are 60 characters long, the salt and hash are base64, but the prefix isn't.

Comment: @mFeinstein - That's OK.  My recommendation still works (after I fixed a typo!)

Comment: could you just elaborate on the pros of using ascii_bin collation? I am not a specialist on DBs, so I am not aware about all the benefits and protections provided.

Comment: I added a paragraph.