# Bcrypt hashedSecret too short to be a bcrypted password

Tags: go, bcrypt

I want to create a user authentication system using Go and I am stuck with logging into an account. I use bcrypt to hash passwords than I save it to the database (MySQL). The problem shows when I want to compare it with an inserted password. I have this error: `hashedSecret too short to be a bcrypted password`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

`models.go`

```
type User struct {
    ID       string `json:"id"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    IsAdmin  bool   `json:"is_admin"`
}
```

`user-routes.go (login func)`

```
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?", user.Username).Scan(&storedPass)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // hashed password
    fmt.Println(storedPass, []byte(storedPass))
    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(storedPass), []byte(user.Password))
    if err != nil {
        // Here is error
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
```

`user-routes.go (register func)`

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, IsAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, 0)`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
hash, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(user.Password), 10)
res, err := stmt.Exec(user.Username, string(hash))
```

It looks like the error is when I compare hashed password with an inserted password. Also, I save a password to a database without any errors.

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| ID | Username | Password                                           | IsAdmin |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 38 | test2    | $2a$10$5WwRQahtjgmaeIKRGXGZNOLVAv5EXUidRwbnZeryq9e |       0 |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Whats the type and length of the password column in your database?

Comment: It's `varchar(50)`

Comment: Thats too short.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks. I changed a length of column and everything works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bcrypt` produces hashes of 59-60 bytes (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d) for details). In order to store the hash as `varchar`, you need to ensure its size is sufficient. According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008351/bcrypt-hashedsecret-too-short-to-be-a-bcrypted-password#comment89009919_51008351), you use `varchar(50)`, which is not enough, and that's the reason that changing its size fixed your problem.