# Converting VARBINARY values into String in a Select Query in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, authentication, password-hash

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d), I should save my **String** BCrypt hashed password, `passHash`, as a `BINARY` or `BINARY(60)` (I chose `BINARY(60)`) when storing it in my MySQL table (I stored it in a column named `passHash`).

Now when I select and retrieve that `passHash` column value from my table into Java, it is now a `byte[]` data type.

How do I then convert it back to its **String** form so that I can validate it using my `validateLogin()` method below:

```
//Validate username and password login
    public boolean validateLogin(String username, String userpass) 
    {
        boolean status = false;  
        PreparedStatement pst = null; 
        ResultSet rs = null;  

        User user = new User(); //This is my Java bean class

        try(Connection connect= DBConnection.getConnection())
        {
            //Here, passHash is stored as VARBINARY(60) 
            pst = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=? and passHash=?;"); 

            pst.setString(1, username);  
            pst.setString(2, userpass);  
            //Here's where I'm having difficulty because `passHash` column in my user table is VARBINARY(60) while `userpass` is a String

            rs = pst.executeQuery(); 
            status = rs.next();  
        } 

        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return status;  //status will return `true` if `username` and `userpass` matches what's in the columns
    }
```

The parameters `username` and `userpass` are being used to get the user's input in my `Login.jsp` form:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String userpass = request.getParameter("userpass");
```

**EDIT**:  My BCrypt code is as follows:

```
//returns a hashed String value
public static String bCrypt (String passPlain) {
        return BCrypt.hashpw(passPlain, BCrypt.gensalt(10));
    }

//Returns a true if plain password is a match with hashed password
public static Boolean isMatch(String passPlain, String passHash){
        return (BCrypt.checkpw(passPlain, passHash));
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this link https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/

Comment: Also as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html the values are actually `Strings` so maybe the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d) is not correct?

Comment: @ScaryWombat So you suggest I change my `passHash1 data type into a `VARCHAR(60)` instead?

Comment: actually I don't see what the fuss is, String to byte use `String::getBytes` byte to String use `new String (bytes)` store in the DB however you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your user accounts, you must be hashing the passwords in some way to generate a `byte[]` in Java, which you then insert into your `user` table.

```
public static byte[] bCrypt (String passPlain) {
    return BCrypt.hashpw(passPlain, BCrypt.gensalt(10)).getBytes();
}

// here is how you generate the hash
byte[] hashed = bCrypt(userpass).toBytes();

// here is how you authenticate a login
String password; // from the UI
String sql = "SELECT passHash FROM user WHERE username = ?";
pst = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, username);
rs = pst.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    byte[] hash = rs.getBytes(1);
    if (isMatch(password, new String(hash))) {
        // authenticate
    }
}
```

The pattern for checking an existing password is to pass in the plain text password and the hash.

Comment: My hash function returns a hashed String value instead of a byte[] (as noted in my EDIT above).  When I save and insert this String value in the `passHash` column in my MySQL table,  i used `setString(myHashedStringPassword)`.

Comment: @JamesMcTyre My answer does not change much.  It isn't clear why your hashing function returns a `String` when your table is storing a `byte[]`.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate all your help.  But if I try to refactor my `bCrypt()` into returning a `byte()` I will have to do more work backwards because `hashpw()` is supposed to return a `String`.  Is there any way I can just convert the original returned `String` into a `byte[]` for my `bCrypt()`?

Comment: Yes, I already told you this, use `String#getBytes()`.  But, if your schema requires a binary input, then why not have your code be consistent?  I mean, what are you doing with a hashed password string besides sticking it into your user table?

Comment: I pinpointed the problem:  `pst.setBytes(2, hashed)` (or `pst.setString(2, hashedString)`) is comparing the actual string on a character-by-character basis.  For example, if the value stored my `passHash` column is `$2a$10$gnzKum16RdSXjoNk5fdv7u` then login would only work if `hashedString` (or its equivalent converted byte[] `hashed`) is also EXACTLY `$2a$10$gnzKum16RdSXjoNk5fdv7u`.  The problem is:  BCrypt generates many different hashes for the same password.  So a password like `helloWorld` can generate the above hash or a different hash.  And that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: `return (BCrypt.checkpw(passPlain, passHash));` should take care of that