# Unable to save an encrypted password with BCryptPassword in database

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to save an encrypted password in postgreSQL database with BCrypt and I have an error. I saw the other answers on stackoverflow I tried to use those hints but I have the same error:This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Aug 25 19:37:41 EEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.save(Unknown Source)
....
at com.car.carDealer.service.UserService.saveUser(UserService.java:38)
at com.car.carDealer.controller.Register.register(Register.java:46)

My code is:

```
    > > @Configuration 
         public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    >     @Bean
    >     public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    >         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    >     } 
}
```

> 

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Integer> {
        User findByEmail(String email);
        User findByEmailAndPassword(String email,String password);
}
```

> 

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRep;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRep) {
        this.userRep = userRep;
    }

    public User findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
        return userRep.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRep.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userRep.save(user);
    }
```

> 

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(
            @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "user/register";
        } else {

            User valid = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
            if (valid == null) {
                user.setPassword(bCryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                userService.saveUser(user);
                String msg = " succes!";
                model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
                return "user/register";
            } else {
                String msg = "Please choose another email !";
                model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
```

Comment: It's hard to answer, when the underlying exception is not shown. But are you sure the BCrypt password is even the problem? Did you try `user.setPassword("foo")` and check if this works? Also, the column definition might be to small. You need at least varchar(60) according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882472/5474918

Comment: man you're a genious..that was the correct answer..I've changed to varchar(60) and now it's ok..intially it was 10. thank you

Comment: You should not use ancient technology like `bcrypt` for passwords. The database itself will have better password-hashing functions than this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it out. Once I remove the validation it ecrypts the password & store it in database. But when I put validations like: password must be 8 to 15 characters, and Even I fulfil this condition but it does not store it in data and gives this error

Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction