# MySQL IF statement not working if condition input is BINARY

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure along these lines:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UserUpdate`(IN inUserId INT, IN inUserFname VARCHAR(40), IN inUserLname VARCHAR(40), IN inUserEmail VARCHAR(40), IN inUserPhone VARCHAR(40), IN inUserPassword BINARY(60))
BEGIN
    IF inUserPassword='' THEN
        UPDATE `users`
        SET fname=inUserFname, lname=inUserLname, email=inUserEmail, phone=inUserPhone, datemodified=NOW()
        WHERE id=inUserId;
    ELSE
        UPDATE `users`
        SET fname=inUserFname, lname=inUserLname, email=inUserEmail, phone=inUserPhone, password=inUserPassword, datemodified=NOW()
        WHERE id=inUserId;
    END IF;
END
```

The information is coming from a HTML Form/PHP script. If the user has not updated their password, then the inUserPassword remains blank and `IF` portion of the procedure should run. If the user has updated their password in the form, then the `ELSE` portion should run.

The password is stored as a bcrypt hash and the column in the database is set as BINARY(60).

The problem that I'm running into is that I can't trigger the `IF` if the BINARY is used for the password. If I change the password column to VARCHAR, the above query works just fine. I understand that the binary value is not the same as ASCII or Unicode value, but for *nothing*, as in the above code, shouldn't it be the same?

How should I go about fixing it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you just convert both to binary?

IF binary(inUserPassword)=binary('') THEN

Comment: Specify the collation for empty string explicitly - like `IF inUserPassword = '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin' THEN` (specify correct collation).

Comment: Thank you. Neither of these changes unfortunately change the behaviour.

Comment: For what it's worth, [password hashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) from php are usually stored in tables as `VARCHAR(255)`, not `BINARY`, data. [Password verification](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) accepts those string, not binary.  Consider changing your data type.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks. I was going based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882472/2912859. I might as well switch back to VARCHAR, but I'm also still curious what's causing the problem above.

Comment: That stuff is really ancient. As time goes by and cybercreeps get smarter, password hashes get longer, You want your password hash column declared as `password VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii` to work in the present and to be future proof. Really.

Comment: @O.Jones roger that!