# Recovery of Hash from Registry

Tags: c#, security, registry, bcrypt

I wrote a basic application that uses bcrypt to hash a password and stores the hashed password and the corresponding salt in the Windows registry as a reg_binary in 'secureValue'. Is there a way to recover this hash value and attempt to crack it? This is my first crack at writing a semi secure app (this IS NOT FOR PRODUCTION ITS JUST FOR LEARNING). I realize the attacker would need to still brute force the corresponding hash but it still seems a potential issue to me. I experimented a bit with recovering it with C# but I cannot recover the value and attempt to crack which seems like a good thing? For instance this doesn't give me a useful return that could then be plugged into a tool like hashcat:

```
            byte[] array = (byte[])rk.GetValue("secureValue");
            string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
            decoded = decoded.Replace("\0", String.Empty);
```

Am I missing something here? Should this be a value you could capture and plug into a tool like hashcat?

*To clarify I am not asking if it is possible to reverse the hash. I am aware this is not possible. What I am asking specifically is if it is possible to recover the hash value from the registry key where it is stored as a REG_BINARY. VNC for instance used to store its hashed password as a REG_SZ value in the windows registry, so you could take that string, and attempt to crack it. I am asking if this same thing is possible if it is stored in REG_BINARY

EDITED FOR CLARITY

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=are+hashes+reversable&oq=are+hashes+reversable&aqs=edge..69i57j0i13j0i390l3.3184j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: However there is no hashes in your code..... So you might as well ask, can someone read a string I give them. the answer is yes

Comment: I don't expect to be able to recover the password. I am not asking if I can reverse the hashing function, I know I cannot do that. What I wanted to know is whether it is possible to recover the hash value itself, which is obviously not useful until it is cracked. This value is stored in REG_BINARY, so presumably that hash value could be recovered, and then attempts could be made to crack it no?

Comment: Without some actual data it is unknown how the application stores the bcrypt output. One common way would be to store the values hexadecimal like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5881169/150978) but as a developer you can chose any format you like.