# UPPER() and LOWER() not required?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, case-sensitive

For a while I thought, in order for the `WHERE` criteria to be evaluated correctly, I need to account for case sensitivity. I would use `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` when case didn't matter. However, I am finding the below queries produce the same result.

```
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE UPPER(part) = 'SOMEPARTNAME'
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE part        = 'SOMEPARTNAME'
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE part        = 'somepartname'
```

[SQL Case Sensitive String Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969059/sql-case-sensitive-string-compare) explains to use case-sensitive collations. Is this the only way to force case sensitivity? Also, if you had a case-insensitive collation when would `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` be necessary?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common SQL Server default of a case-insensitive collation means that `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` are not required when comparing strings.

In fact an expression such as

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UPPER(part) = 'SOMEPARTNAME'
```

is also non-sargable i.e won't use available indexes, due to the function applied to the `part` column on the left hand side of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

this query below produces `CASE SENSITIVE` search:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'casesearch'
```

`UPPER()` and `LOWER()` are only functions to change the case of the letter so if you  case-insensitive collation, they are only use after the `SELECT` Keyword:

```
SELECT UPPER('qwerty'), LOWER('Dog')

returns
QWERTY, dog
```