# Is database record is case sensitive?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables `City` and `CityCommunity` in City table one column contain `cityName` like this

```
cityName = 'ABC'
```

And in `CityCommunity` table we have same column `cityName` but value of this columnName is something like this

```
 cityName = 'abc'
```

Will it effect in query when we will run a Join query. In my case when I am joining these two table in the above case when both `cityName` same but only difference is case sensitive will it effect query to run

Comment: It depends upon the COLLATION - See [Collation and Unicode Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143503(v=sql.105).aspx) (the default collation is usually "CI" for Case Insensitive.)

Comment: Can say yes and can say No.. it depends. If your DB collation is CS(Case Sensitive) then yes it is if its CI (Case Insensitive) then not.. Generally for UserId nd Password like sensitive information we g for CS.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969059/sql-case-sensitive-string-compare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default it is not case sensitive. So it will treat 'ABC' and 'abc' as same. But to make it case sensitive you have to use COLLATE.
You can find the detailed explanation with example [HERE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/) . This applys to join also.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Yes, the results are case sensitive so if you are looking for
`cityName = 'ABC'`
the results with
`cityName = 'abc'` or `cityName ='Abc'`
won't show!

You need to add UPPER so you can get all results

```
SELECT UPPER(cityName)
FROM City;
```

in this case, no matter what case are the results it will convert the whole column data to upper case