# Login page validation

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to coding in asp.net . I have done a (web form) login page and its validation in asp.net + c#. The problem is when i enter the password corresponding to the email in lower-case/upper-case letters, it grants me entry which is not supposed to happen. I have gone through a number of codes posted here for login page but the same thing is happening.
For eg,if the password in db is "ss"and if we type "ss","Ss", "sS" or "SS" ; i'm able to sign in. How can i stop this from happening?

I'm posting my code here. Please help.

```
protected void btn_login1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHA\SQLE2012;Initial Catalog=OnlineShoppingStore;User ID=sa;Password=56238");
     con.Open(); 
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_ViewUserByUserId", con);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txt_email.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_password.Text);
     string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     if (output =="1")
     { 
         Response.Write("<script>alert('Login Successful!!')</script>");
         Session["Email"] = txt_email.Text;
         Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");            
     }
     else
         Response.Write("<script>alert('Login Failed! Incorrect username/password')</script>");
     con.Close();

 }
```

This is my stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ViewUserByUserId] 
    @Email as varchar(50),
    @Password as varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select count(*) from tbl_Customer  where Email = @Email and Password = @Password

end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969059/sql-case-sensitive-string-compare

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be storing password in plain text. Use a hashing algorithm such as Bcrypt.

Comment: Password encryption is much you needed.

Comment: This is just a sample project. I'm learning from scratch. That is why i haven't used encryption. But yes, i will add password encryption soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for taking the time to give suggestions.
The code below did the trick

```
select count(*) 
from tbl_Customer  
where Email = @Email and BINARY_CHECKSUM(Password) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(@Password)
```