# Visual basic login form with db4free php my admin

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I have made a Visual Basic form for login and register account with sql database from db4free. My question is how can i make the password row matters the Capital letters? So when i enter the username and the password correctly it works but even if i enter the password with non-capital letters it still works. How can i make the password row so it matters if the user enters capital letters on the password text box? If anyone can help me with that i will be really happy. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before you store the password use .ToUpper and when you verify the password use .ToUpper. Of course passwords should never be stored as plain text.

Comment: Yes but this just makes all leters Capital. I mean that when someone makes a password he can put some capital letter to make it stronger but for my password row it doesn't matter if the user put lower or capital letter even if the password is stored with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing the passwords using an actual SQL query, by default, SQL comparisons are case insensitive. Take a look at this stackoverflow question for help:

[SQL Case Sensitive String Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969059/sql-case-sensitive-string-compare)