# VB.NET: How to camel case words that are uppercased

Tags: sql, string

If I have a string "HELLO WORLD"

How can I lowercase every letter after the first one but keep the camel casing so: I get:

Hello World

Comment: Isn't Hello World actually pascal case?
doesn't camel casing mean - helloWorld?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("HELLO WORLD".ToLower())

Comment: nice any way to do this in sql?

Comment: You can try http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/01/sql-server-udf-function-to-convert-text-string-to-title-case-proper-case/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case
But I suggest to do this on the client. SQL just doesn't have the functions to do this eaisly.

Answer (score 5):

Use Proper Case

```
strName = StrConv(strName, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this class in the .NET Framework

System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx

"Generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to uppercase and the rest of the characters to lowercase...."

You might have to do a .ToLower() first according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to convert a string to title casing, in vb.net.

Try this code. It should work fine.

```
Dim title as String = "converted to title case"

Console.WriteLine(StrConv(title, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StrConv("SOME TEXT TO CONVERT", VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

Also check out this article with better code examples:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=555587