# SQL-Server 2008: Proper casing a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Make all UPPER case to Proper Case/Title Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case)

if i have a string "HELLO WORLD"

How can i lowercase every letter after the first one but keep the camel casing so: i get:

Hello World

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would try to do this on the client personally... But you could try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CamelCase]
(@Str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(2000)
  SET @Str = LOWER(@Str) + ' '
  SET @Result = ''
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %',@Str) = 0 BREAK
    SET @Result = @Result + UPPER(Left(@Str,1))+
    SubString  (@Str,2,CharIndex(' ',@Str)-1)
    SET @Str = SubString(@Str,
      CharIndex(' ',@Str)+1,Len(@Str))
  END
  SET @Result = Left(@Result,Len(@Result))
 RETURN @Result
END
```