# Remove white spaces from string and convert into title case

Tags: sql

Here is the example which i want in output...

I have this ***input*** = "**Automatic email sent**"

But I want this ***output*** = "**AutomaticEmailSent**"

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Is this in C# or SQL?

Comment: Understood, any attempt?

Comment: what did you try so far? moreover you want to accomplish this in c# or sql?

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Defines the string with mixed casing. 
string myString = "Automatic email sent";

// Creates a TextInfo based on the "en-US" culture.
TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;

// Changes a string to titlecase, then replace the spaces with empty
string outputString = myTI.ToTitleCase(myString).Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Question updated as an `sql` tag, `c#` is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing a function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230177/1663001) which takes an text input and make it proper case (otherwise known as title case):

```
create function ProperCase(@Text as varchar(8000))
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
   declare @Reset bit;
   declare @Ret varchar(8000);
   declare @i int;
   declare @c char(1);

   select @Reset = 1, @i=1, @Ret = '';

   while (@i <= len(@Text))
    select @c= substring(@Text,@i,1),
               @Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset=1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c) end,
               @Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,
               @i = @i +1
   return @Ret
end
```

Then you can combine this function with [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
SELECT REPLACE(dbo.ProperCase(column), ' ', '')
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers you find useful and if one of them solves your issue, Mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server

```
declare @value varchar(64) =  rtrim(' ' +  'Automatic email sent')
;with t(n) as (
    select n = charindex(' ', @value, 0)
    union all 
    select n = charindex(' ', @value, n + 1)
    from t
    where n > 0
)
select @value = stuff(@value, n + 1, 1, upper(substring(@value, n + 1, 1))) from t where n > 0
select replace(@value, ' ', '')
```