# first letters in firstname and lastname uppercase

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assuming I have a table full of names.

firstname.lastname in a single cell.

How can I seperate these into "Firstname Lastname", with uppercase for the first letters? Using TSQL

Sample:

> mike.mikeson -> Mike Mikeson
>
> katy.lumberjack -> Katy Lumberjack

Comment: Can we trust the format? Is it always firstname, followed by a single space, followed by lastname?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Include Conan O'Brien, Ronald McDonald and other exotic names.

Comment: It would be nice to see what you've tried yourself.

Comment: The case use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case

Comment: another option on title case https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx

Comment: @jarlh I will. But there are no exotic names :)

Comment: It's pretty much impossible. How are you going to determine that "Vincent van Gogh" his last name is "van Gogh" and "Samuel L Jackson" his last name is "Jackson"? There is no real pattern.

Comment: @Ivar The names I use only have the format showed in the sample

Comment: @MrProgram If that is the case, my answer below will work without issue.

Comment: This was trendy a few years back, but it can never work consistently for all name types, there is a name Mackie and a name MacKie for example - how about names like Giscard d'Estang   - yes I read the article by a journalist called Mackie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those times we can use the `ParseName` function for our benefit `;-)`

```
SELECT original_value
     , forename
     , surname
     , Upper(SubString(forename, 1, 1)) + Lower(Substring(forename, 2, 8000)) AS formatted_forename
     , Upper(SubString(surname , 1, 1)) + Lower(Substring(surname , 2, 8000)) AS formatted_surname
FROM   (
        SELECT name AS original_value
             , ParseName(name, 2) AS forename
             , ParseName(name, 1) AS surname
        FROM   (
                VALUES ('mike.mikeson')
                     , ('katy.lumberjack')
               ) AS users (name)
       ) AS step1
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will answer you question as is but as comments have pointed out, you may need to also take into account names that have more than one uppercase letter in either part, such as Mary-Anne McDonald, or those that simply don't conform to your convention.

```
declare @a table (Name nvarchar(50))
insert into @a values
 ('fred.bloggs')
 ,('john.doe')
 ,('alan.smith')

select Name
    ,upper(left(Name,1))
        + substring(Name,2,charindex('.',Name,1)-2)
        + ' '
        + upper(substring(Name,charindex('.',Name,1)+1,1))
        + right(Name,len(Name) - charindex('.',Name,1)-1)
        as FormattedName
from @a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using concat and substring for this as below

```
declare @name varchar(50) = 'firstname.lastname'

select case when charindex('.',@name) > 0 then  concat(upper(left(@name,1)), substring(@name,2,charindex('.',@name)-2), ' ', upper(substring(@name,charindex('.',@name)+1,1)), substring(@name,charindex('.',@name)+2, len(@name)))
            else concat(upper(left(@name,1)), substring(@name,2,len(@name))) end
```