# SQL Server Convert case for letter that comes after - (hyphen)

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert case for letter that comes after hyphen (-) in all values of a column

like

```
Aaa - aaa
Bbbdd - bbbdd
Ccc123 - ccc123
```

to

```
Aaa - Aaa
Bbbdd - Bbbdd
Ccc123 - Ccc123
```

Please help!

Comment: upper case only first Char of string after -?

Comment: Your pattern is static always like n characters then space then hyphen then space and n characters?

Comment: you can use upper

Comment: @KannanKandasamy not its not static it can be of any length any characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stuff()`:

```
declare @str varchar(64) = 'Aaa - aaa'

select stuff(@str,charindex('-',@str)+2,1,upper(substring(@str,charindex('-',@str)+2,1)))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CCIZDT37194

Returns: `Aaa - Aaa`

Answer (score 0):

Well if the format doesn't change here's an easy way. It works for n - n characters

```
declare @char varchar(64) = 'Aaa - aaa'

select 
    @char
    ,substring(@char,1,CHARINDEX('-',@char,1)) + ' ' + upper(substring(@char,CHARINDEX('-',@char,1) + 2,1)) + substring(@char,CHARINDEX('-',@char,1)+3,len(@char))
```

Otherwise you [need a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case)

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Aaa - aaa';
DECLARE @Index INT = CharIndex('-', @InputString);
DECLARE @StringToReplace VARCHAR(3) = SUBSTRING ( @InputString ,@Index , 3 );

SELECT REPLACE(@InputString,@StringToReplace,UPPER(@StringToReplace));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use upper and ParseName

```
select concat(parsename(Replace(v,' - ', '.'),2), ' - ', Upper(substring(parsename(Replace(v,' - ', '.'),1),1,1)), substring(parsename(Replace(v,' - ', '.'),1),2,len(parsename(Replace(v,' - ', '.'),1)))) 
    from #yourtext
```

Your Input table:

```
create table #yourtext (v varchar(100))

insert into #yourtext (v) values
 ('Aaa - aaa')
,('Bbb - bbb')
,('Ccc - ccc')
```