Convert title case to sentence case: A MySQL query to capitalize the first letter of each sentence within a database column
I have a MySQL database in which one column is filled with sentences in title-case format. Each of the existing sentences ends with a period, and the sentences are separated from each other by a space. How can I convert all the text to sentence-case format?
For example, the text initially looks like this:

This Is A Dog. That Is A Cat.

I call that "title case", or "proper case", but what I need instead is "sentence case". I mean only the first letter of each sentence should be capitalized.
The query output should be:

This is a dog. That is a cat.


What is the use case to do it in DB rather than in application layer?

I sometimes need to update my database manually, which I do in HeidiSQL. Have I answered your question?

Ideally it should be in Application layer or in front end.

@Amit, I guess you mean that I should have coded a web page to perform this task. I think you are assuming that other users or customers have access to my database, but they don't. As a sole proprietor, I needed to do this task by myself, just once. I do need to run custom queries on my data occasionally, and I've been doing it for decades without any problems. Of course, I always back-up my database beforehand, so there is no risk. That said, I imagine you are far more knowledgeable than I am - I'm not a pro - so if I have missed your point, please explain your meaning in more detail. Thanks!

@Photon The tasks related to formatting should be done at frontend as it is not related to any business logic or any manipulation with the data should be done at application layer. There is nothing wrongdoing at DB level, but it will be a load on DB. My above comment is only related to this thought. It has nothing to do with DB security.

@Amit  I see what you mean. But for people like me who need to manipulate data, SQL is actually very useful. For example, here is a related question that has attracted considerable interest:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/230138/4403012 . Anyway, my database is on my local server. It is not accessible to the public. After modifying the data, I uploaded it to the remote server for the website, but it is a legacy site that attracts a very low volume of visitors. I guess you work with large databases on high volume websites, in which case your concern does seem valid. Thanks for your suggestion!

I tried the following code and it worked.
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION CapitalizeSentences(input_text TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE output_text TEXT;
    DECLARE period_pos INT;
    DECLARE sentence_start_pos INT;

    SET output_text = CONCAT(
        UPPER(SUBSTRING(input_text, 1, 1)),
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(input_text, 2))
    );

    SET period_pos = LOCATE('. ', output_text);
    WHILE period_pos > 0 DO
        SET sentence_start_pos = period_pos + 2;
        SET output_text = CONCAT(
            LEFT(output_text, sentence_start_pos - 1),
            UPPER(SUBSTRING(output_text, sentence_start_pos, 1)),
            SUBSTRING(output_text, sentence_start_pos + 1)
        );
        SET period_pos = LOCATE('. ', output_text, sentence_start_pos);
    END WHILE;

    RETURN output_text;
END //

DELIMITER ;


UPDATE table_name
SET `col_name` = CapitalizeSentences(`col_name`);

